# Extract all the code at a particular commit

Tags: git

I would like to extract all the code at a particular commit (show in blue highlight below) in GitExtensions. I want to leave all the commits after that in tact and want to extract the code to a different location on the hard drive than than existing code. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the commit and select "Archive revision" and then click the "Save as" button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out that commit, copy and paste the code somewhere outside the repository, then check out the last commit again.

Comment: This works but it has a a drawback in that changes that are not committed will be lost. Also, it just makes me nervous, but that's just my paranoia. :)